# Insert Int32 instead of decimal in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have simple question in mongodb

when i am trying to insert as decimal i got int32 in db

I try this :

```
   db.col.insertOne({"test_number":20.0})
```

And I got this in db :

```
 { _id: ObjectId("613f3e8a36ed56de6e7f91a0"), number: 20 }
```

But i wanna get decimal number instead of int
I want to save in db as decimal not int32

[image]

[image]

Comment: BTW, decimals and floating-point numbers (floats) usually mean different things. I think here you mean the latter.

Answer (score 0):

> when i am trying to insert as decimal i got int32 in db

Nope. This number is stored as BSON type "double". What you see is how javascript handles numbers and it has nothing to do with mongodb.

Try this in any JS console:

```js
var a = 20.0;
console.log(a);
```

---

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/

```
> db.col.insertOne({"test_number":20.0})
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "insertedId" : ObjectId("613f4f4e3a9b167fe06f00ed")
}
> db.col.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("613f4f4e3a9b167fe06f00ed"), "test_number" : 20 }
> db.col.find({test_number: { $type: 16}}) // int 32
> db.col.find({test_number: { $type: 19}}) // decimal
> db.col.find({test_number: { $type: 1}}) // double
{ "_id" : ObjectId("613f4f4e3a9b167fe06f00ed"), "test_number" : 20 }
```

Comment: my problem is how can i save 20.0 or numbers like this in db .

Comment: @MiladVayani They _are_ saved as doubles, as you can clearly see.